# Путь к подключаемым файлам из owl carousel 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, битрикс, установка, owl-carousel

Скачал [Owl Carousel](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/) . На [Инcтрукция по использования Owl Carousel](https://webformyself.com/slajder-owl-carousel-2-ustanovka-i-nastrojka/) написано, что нужно подключать файлы `owl.carousel.css` и `owl.theme.default.css`. Из какой папки скачанного архива с [Owl Carousel](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/) нужно брать эти файлы - из `dist` или из `docs/assets` или из `src`?